# UITextView textviewshouldendediting never called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview, uitextview

I have a UITextView setup like this:

```
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 280, 240)];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:13]];
    [textView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [textView setText:@"Your Message...."];
    [textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [textView setDelegate:self];
    [textView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

I am expecting that when the user pressed the "Done" button on keyboard, this method will be invoked (which I have implemented):

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSLog(@"called");
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

But this method never get's called..What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Where did you define the `textViewShouldEndEditing:` method? Is it in the `self` instance you are using above?

Answer (score 4):

While you set the return key type, it doesn't alter text view's behavior. On `Return`, it will add a newline to the text view. So if you don't want your text view to be multiline, you can capture the `\n` and `resignFirstResponder`.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ( [text isEqualToString:@"\n"] ) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

On a side note, `textViewShouldEndEditing:` is called after you resign your first responder status.

If you want to retain newline characters in your text view, you should consider using the [`inputAccessoryView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006783-CH4-SW24) of the text view. An example for that is [`here`](http://pastie.org/1962865).