# Handling 'Done' button on the keyboard outside of textViewDidEndEditing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, keyboard

When "Done" is pressed I know `textViewDidEndEditing:` is called. It is also sometimes called by other actions.

I want a method that is only called when "Done" is pressed -- exclusively. I've been reading around for snippets of code, but don't see anybody doing this. I am not using any XIB for my view, by the way.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106761/uitextview-textviewshouldendediting-never-called/6107507#6107507   Refer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,  the textFieldDidEndEditing is called not when the user taps the DONE button. **It is called as soon as you touch anything after editing.**

For having an exclusive button 'Done' you can create a Done key as a UIBarButtonItem, and write an IBAction like

```
- (IBAction) doneClicked:(id)sender
```

The following line assigns the Done key as the Return Key.

```
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

You can check if the Done key was pressed in the TextFieldDidEndEditing...You may also use another button, and return it instead.

Comment: Hi Legolas, Maybe my question was not clear. I want to be able to handle the event of the Done button on the Keyboard being pressed. Is there some way to catch this event without using textViewDidEndEditing? Many Thanks, Code

Comment: @Legolas, your first statement is incorrect. Touching other views doesn't automatically steal first responder status from the text field that's currently editing -- if that was true, you could never type anything on the keyboard.

Answer (score 14):

An instance of UITextField will send a `textFieldShouldReturn:` message to its delegate whenever the Return key is pressed. If you want your controller to receive this message, have it send a `setDelegate:` message to the text field, passing `self` as the argument (or connect the text field's delegate outlet to the controller in Interface Builder) and implement the following method in your controller class:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

See the documentation for the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol for further information.